# How to stop erase of data after clicking erase option mistakenly in android device manager

Tags: motorola-moto-g2

I have lost my motog2 mobile and mistakenly pressed to erase the data after using the option lock of android device manager.And later on got to know that the option deletes total data and I will not be able to atleast track my mobile location.so I want to stop the erase option to perform, before my mobile got internet connection and got data erased.please suggest a way for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you issued the command to erase the phone, there is no taking it back.

If the device you sent the erase command to does not have service, it would not receive the command; but then you would not be able to track the disconnected device either.

Once it gets an internet connection, and receives the command to erase, it will start.

If you happen to find the device prior to it receiving the command to erase, you may be able to remove Android Device Manager to prevent loss of data.